# Check which variables can be side-effected by expression evaluation in Clang AST

Tags: clang

`clang::Expr` has the member function [`HasSideEffects(const ASTContext &Ctx, bool IncludePossibleEffects)`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Expr.html#a94846e4728dc634c3af14e7c3a62e47c). In my case I want to be more precise, and to know that e.g. an `Expr` corresponding to `Y++` will only affect `Y` and not `X`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This predicate is rather simple, however, its simplicity and even the ability to work are bound to the fact that it doesn't try to list those exact side-effects.

Clang is only a front-end for LLVM and doesn't do tricky analysis of the code (except for clang static analyzer component). The main problem is the problem of *aliases*, i.e. trying to figure out what other variables can be affected by an arbitrary modification of pointer/reference.

Simple example:

```cpp
int X = 42;
int &Y = X;
Y++;
```

Does `Y++` affect `X` in this case? - Yes.

Can we understand it? - Yes, if we trace what `Y` refers to.

Is it possible? - Generally speaking, no. We're limited with the knowledge of the current translation unit. And even if it is the whole program, it takes way too long to do precisely. There are a lot of different trade-offs and techniques to do it rather fast and precise, but it's definitely not a part of the front-end compiler.

Comment: "except for clang static analyzer component" Do you know if something like that is implemented in clang-static-analizer or clang-tidy then? That's where I want it actually.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that the requested functionality is bundled somewhere inside of the static analyzer in a desired form. I do think that the info available there would be enough to design such a solution, but it's not going to be trivial.

Comment: C++ is complex enough that I think it would be difficult to get correct enough (at least for me), so I hoped someone did the work already. Oh well, I'll live with just `HasSideEffects`.